# PHP pThreads - How do you perform garbage collection?

Tags: php, multithreading, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, pthreads

Given the following code, how can you ensure that the completed MyWorker objects are destroyed/their memory freed?

Due to what my script does I need ~50 threads constantly obtaining data from cURL, and processing it.

I've tried both having the threads never leave `run()`, or as shown in this sample code where they leave run and have the collect function spawn a new copy of them.

But not matter what I hit the memory limits after a minute or so. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
class MyWorker extends Threaded
{
    public $complete;
    public function __construct() {$this->complete = false;}
    public function run() {$this->complete = true;}
}

$pool = new Pool(50);
for($i=0; $i<50; $i++)
    $pool->submit(new MyWorker());
$pool->collect(function($worker)
{
    global $pool;
    if($worker->complete == true)
        $pool->submit(new MyWorker());
    return $worker->complete;
});
$pool->shutdown();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Why

*Why should I collect anyway ?*

The `Worker` threads provided by pthreads require that the programmer retain the correct references to `Threaded` objects that are being executed. This is difficult for the programmer to achieve in userland reliably, so pthreads provides the `Pool` abstraction of `Workers` which maintains references for you.

In order to maintain those reference pthreads needs to know when an object is garbage, it provides the `Pool::collect` interface for this purpose. `Pool::collect` takes a Closure which should accept a `Threaded` object and return boolean `true` if the passed object is finished executing.

## How

*The task at hand ...*

In order to keep submitting tasks for execution and not exhaust resources, you must create a queue of completed tasks for resubmission to the `Pool`

The following code demonstrates a sane way of doing this:

```
<?php

define("LOG", Mutex::create());
/* thread safe log to stdout */
function slog($message, $args = []) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    if (($message = array_shift($args))) {
        Mutex::lock(LOG);
        echo vsprintf(
            "{$message}\n", $args);
        Mutex::unlock(LOG);
    }
}

class Request extends Threaded {
    public function __construct($url) {
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function run() {
        $response = @file_get_contents($this->url);

        slog("%s returned %d bytes",
            $this->url, strlen($response));

        $this->reQueue();
    }

    public function getURL()        { return $this->url; }

    public function isQueued()      { return $this->queued; }
    public function reQueue()       { $this->queued = true; }

    protected $url;
    protected $queued = false;
}

/* create a pool of 50 threads */
$pool = new Pool(50);

/* submit 50 requests for execution */
while (@$i++<50) {
    $pool->submit(new Request(sprintf(
        "http://google.com/?q=%s", md5($i))));
}

do {
    $queue = array();

    $pool->collect(function($request) use ($pool, &$queue) {
        /* check for items to requeue */
        if ($request->isQueued()) {
            /* get the url for the request, insert into queue */
            $queue[] = 
                $request->getURL();
            /* allow this job to be collected */
            return true;
        }
    });

    /* resubmit completed tasks to pool */
    if (count($queue)) {
        foreach ($queue as $queued)
            $pool->submit(new Request($queued));
    }

    /* sleep for a couple of seconds here ... because, be nice ! */
    usleep(2.5 * 1000000);
} while (true);
?>
```