# How does Pool::collect works?

Tags: php, callback, pthreads, threadpool

Help me understand how exactly Pool::collect works.

**Pool::collect — Collect references to completed tasks**

```
public void Pool::collect ( Callable $collector )
```

What I assume was: `Pool::collect` registers a function, which will be called after each `\Threaded $task` is completed. So, I did:

```
<?php
$pool = new Pool(4);
$pool->collect($collector);
$pool->submit(new Task);
```

Didn't work. But the following does:

```
<?php
$pool = new Pool(4);
$pool->submit(new Task);
$pool->collect($collector);
```

So, I guess what `Pool::collect` does is: attaches the `$collector` to each `\Threaded $task` previously submitted.

Now, when exactly the `$collector` is called? I assume was called after `Threaded::run()` is completed. Wrong again.

```
<?php
class Task extends Threaded {
    public function run () { echo "Task complete\n"; }
}

$collector = function (\Task $task) {
    echo "Collect task\n";
    return true;
};

$pool = new Pool(4);
$pool->submit(new Task);
$pool->collect($collector);
$pool->shutdown();
```

Outputs:

```
Collect task
Task complete
```

`$collector` is called before `Threaded::run()` is completed.

---

The documentation doesn't say much. Doesn't event say that the `$collector` must return a boolean value. [I didn't know that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23384025/3333776).

**I was trying to use Pool::collect as kind of a callback after each $task is completed. I think I'm in the wrong path.**

Edit 1. [What about this attempt](http://pastebin.com/GdPgSjvH)?

Answer (score 4):

`Pool::collect` traverses a list of objects passing each one to the `$collector`.

The `$collector` function should return `true` when the engine can destroy the reference to the `Threaded` object in the work list.

### In PHP7

The `::collect` functionality was moved to `Worker`, though it's still exposed by `Pool` for utility.

There are two lists, one list of items ready to be executed, and another of items that have been executed (or is currently being executed).

`Pool::collect` traverses the second list, items that have been executed (or is currently being executed).

`Pool::collect` returns the number of items still left in the garbage list for all `Worker` objects in the `Pool` to aid with scheduling garbage collection.

### PHP7 Code

```
<?php
$pool = new Pool(4);

while (@$i++<10) {
    $pool->submit(new class($i) extends Threaded {
        public function __construct($id) {
            $this->id = $id;
        }

        public function run() {
            printf(
                "Hello World from %d\n", $this->id);
        }

        public $id;
    });
}

while ($pool->collect(function(Collectable $work){
    printf(
        "Collecting %d\n", $work->id);
    return $work->isGarbage();
})) continue;

$pool->shutdown();
?>
```

Will yield something like:

```
Hello World from 1
Hello World from 2
Hello World from 3
Hello World from 4
Hello World from 8
Collecting 1
Hello World from 7
Hello World from 5
Collecting 5
Hello World from 6
Collecting 9
Collecting 2
Collecting 6
Collecting 10
Hello World from 9
Collecting 3
Collecting 7
Collecting 4
Hello World from 10
Collecting 8
Collecting 5
Collecting 10
```

Comment: This example doesn't work with the latest pthreads oh PHP7. `Collectable` is an interface now and even if I update it I run into this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40854207/using-pool-class-in-php7-pthreads-extension

Answer (score 0):

You missed the audit cycle.
Task can not be completed immediately, so at first the collect function  do not receive positive result. Several times need to check, it requires a cycle.

In the example if infinite is true, always 4 tasks working. Otherwise, if size of queue is equal with pool size (4), it is over, you can exit the loop.

```
<?php

class Task extends \Threaded
{

    protected $result;
    protected $completed = false;

    public function run()
    {
        echo "Task complete\n";
        $this->result = md5(rand(1, 2000));
        sleep(rand(1, 5));
        $this->completed = true;
    }

    public function isCompleted()
    {
        return $this->completed;
    }

    public function getResult()
    {
        return $this->result;
    }
}

$infinite = false;
$poolSize = 4;
$queue = array();

$pool = new \Pool($poolSize);
$pool->submit(new Task);
$pool->submit(new Task);
$pool->submit(new Task);
$pool->submit(new Task);


do {
    if($infinite === true){
        $queue = array();
    }

    $pool->collect(function (\Task $task) use (&$queue) {
        if ($task->isCompleted()) {
            echo "Collect task\n";
            $queue[] = $task->getResult();

            return true;
        } else {
            echo "task not complete\n";

            return false;
        }
    });

    $size = sizeof($queue);
    if ($size > 0) {

        echo $size . " result\n";
        print_r($queue);

        if($infinite === true) {
            for ($m = 0; $m < $size; $m++) {
                $pool->submit(new Task);
            }
        } else{
            if($size == $poolSize){
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    usleep(100000);

} while (true);
$pool->shutdown();
```